# Datatables not initialising after ajax call

Tags: ajax, datatables

I'm using ajax to run a query and return the output in a :

```
<form action="" class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="alarm_text">Hub Site: </label>
<select name="Site" onchange="showCustomer(this.value)" class="form-control">
<option value="">Select a site</option>
<cfoutput query="groupCount">
<option value="#HSEN#">#HS#</option>
</cfoutput>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="txtHint" style="margin-bottom: 50px;" style="border: 1px solid red;">
</div>

<script>
function showCustomer(str) {
                    var xhttp;
                    if (str == "") {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                    }
                    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                    };
                    xhttp.open("GET", "FindAlarmRecords.cfm?q="+str, true);
                    xhttp.send();
                    }

                    $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#RARData').DataTable(
                    );
                    });
                </script>
```

The resultant output is passed into a DataTable, but its not initialising (ie showing the pagination etc):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#RARData').DataTable(
);
});
</script>
```

I'm new to the whole java / ajax world. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks all.

Comment: Is `FindAlarmRecords.cfm` where the table data is coming from?

Comment: Yes - its just parsing the form field 'q' into the where clause: 
'code'    <cfquery datasource="cfADS_Dev" name="GetResults">
 select [Date] as RecDate
 ,[Total Received] as TRec
 ,[Total Resolved] as TRes
 ,[Total Passed Out] as TPO
 ,[Alarm Text] as AT
 ,[Works Shutdown] as WS
 ,[AddedBy]
 ,[Date Added] as DateAdded
 ,[Hub Site] as HS
 ,[Sub Site] as SS
 ,ID
 FROM [ADS_Dev].[WTWPT].[AlarmRecords]
 where  [HSEN] = '#q#'
 order by [Hub Site], [Sub Site]
</cfquery>

Comment: You need to use the datatables API to load data via ajax. Have a look at this: [www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/jquery-datatables-and-java-integration.html](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/jquery-datatables-and-java-integration.html)